# titanium android: close application completely (no caching)

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

When user presses the back button, titanium application gets closed. But the application can be viewed in cached processes list (under settings-->applications-->running services-->menu pressed-->show cached processes). I want my application to get killed completely when it gets closed. (Just FYI, I am using titanium android module.) Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There is a boolean property on the window for Android only.  Before opening the window, set `win.exitOnClose = true;`

Comment: I am using tabgroup. there are 3 tabs each having one window (win1, win2, win3). I have set `exitOnClose : true` for each window. but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: This wont work with a tab group, just independent windows.  If you want, you can remap the android:back event:  `win.addEventListener('android:back', function(){//do something});`

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.  Chez Android, quitting your application is considered bad practice.  Users don't "quit" your app, they navigate away and may decide to return, and expect to find it in the same state they as left it.  If you are going to depart from this nearly universal usage paradigm, you should have an extremely good reason.

Comment: my titanium app gets opened by a broadcast receiver. Boradcast receiver works perfectly fine. When the broadcast receiver opens the titanium app, titanium app gets crashed sometimes. So, I think if I can configure my titanium application such a way that it does not get cached, the problem may get solved. (its just a thought, just want to do for testing if application gets crashed or not). so, can you help me configuring the app such that it never gets cached?