# Application stays in cache even after quitting in Android Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I have created an application for android and I am facing a critical problem. My application should quit when I press the back button. On pressing back button, I am coming out of the application, but the application is getting cached in the memory.

If I go here: under settings-->applications-->running services-->menu pressed-->show cached processes 
I can see the application.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739776/titanium-android-close-application-completely-no-caching) and found some solutions. I have implemented them with no effects.

For the window from which I want to quit the application, I have added this:

```
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        navBarHidden:true,
        exitOnClose:true
    });
```

To kill the activity, I did something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('android:back', function(e){

    var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
    activity.finish();

    //alert("Back Clicked!");

});
```

But still if I check the cached processes, I can see the app running. What should I do to stop the application completely on pressing back button?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your event listener and just changing the window definition to:

```
...
navBarHidden: false,
...
```

Comment: No its all the same, secondly removing exitOnClose:true takes me back to the splash screen on clicking the back button

Comment: Did you change all window definitions to navBarHidden: false?  I remember in my app it would close on hitting the back button.  For my users it was the opposite, very annoying for them.